# Sorting by relation property

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here's my working database setup:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID")
    private Set<Bar> bars;

//...

}

@Entity
class Bar {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;
    //...
}
```

FooRepository extends CrudRepository {

```
@Query("select distinct f from Foo f left join f.bars b where b.status = :status ")
public Page<Bar> findByBarStatus(@Param("status") BarStatus status, Pageable pageable);
```

}

I'd like to be able to sort this query by `Bar.status`, here's how I tried to change the query:

```
@Query("select distinct f from Foo f left join f.bars b where b.status = :status order by b.status desc")
public Set<Bar> findByBarStatus(@Param("status") BarStatus status);
```

However that causes sql syntax error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Order by expression "BARS1_.STATUS" must be in the result list in this case;
```

Comment: `select distinct f, b.status .... `

Answer (score 2):

Here you have applied distinct on `f` and thus you can not have some other column in order by. Actually, order by item must be there in select list.

So, the problem is in query, you can remove distinct if you are sure that `f` will be unique (but that's not the case I *guess*) or you can try `with` clause,

```
with temp as  
(select distinct f, b.status 
 from Foo f left join f.bars b 
 where b.status = :status order by b.status desc) 
select f from temp
```

Comment: That didin't work. 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method

Comment: it works without the `with` wrapper, but returns the both values. So I guess there's a syntax error in wrapper

Comment: Okay.. I think you need to set `nativeQuery=true` in query annotation to make this work. i.e. `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value= <<supply-query-string>>)`

Comment: I'm actually want to keep the Pageable and some other features that I don't think I can do in native mode

Comment: Can I somehow use @SqlResultSetMapping in this case or at least agregate the result of this query into wrapper object?

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `b.status` in your query select statement like below query.

```
    select DISTINCT(f), b.status from Foo f
 LEFT JOIN f.bars b where b.status = :status order by b.status desc
```